# Out of Memory when UrlEncodedFormEntity with an image

Tags: android, image, image-processing, out-of-memory

I'm trying to send data to a server. That is, some string fields and an image, which is encoded as base64 and passed as a String like this:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        mBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
        byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
        //Cleaning memory
        try {
            stream.close();
            stream = null;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        //Eecode base64
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair(DatosDB.KEY_IMG, Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, Base64.DEFAULT)));
        byteArray = null;
```

And then, when preparing the HTTP PUT request:

```
 try{
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        //PUT
        HttpPut httpput = new HttpPut(KEY_121 + ruta);
        //The exception is thrown when executing next instruction
        httpput.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpput);

        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        is = entity.getContent();

        }catch(Exception e){
        Log.e(TAG, "Error in http connection "+e.toString());
        }
```

The error looks like this:

```
12-20 00:24:11.622: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7499): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-20 00:24:11.622: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7499): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
12-20 00:24:11.622: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7499):     at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.enlargeBuffer(AbstractStringBuilder.java:95)
12-20 00:24:11.622: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7499):     at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append0(AbstractStringBuilder.java:140)
12-20 00:24:11.622: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7499):     at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:125)
12-20 00:24:11.622: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7499):     at java.net.URLEncoder.encode(URLEncoder.java:109)
12-20 00:24:11.622: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7499):     at org.apache.http.client.utils.URLEncodedUtils.encode(URLEncodedUtils.java:184)
12-20 00:24:11.622: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7499):     at org.apache.http.client.utils.URLEncodedUtils.format(URLEncodedUtils.java:163)
12-20 00:24:11.622: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7499):     at org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity.<init>(UrlEncodedFormEntity.java:71)
12-20 00:24:11.622: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7499):     at com.android.upvar.Http_Request.put(Http_Request.java:171)
12-20 00:24:11.622: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7499):     at com.android.upvar.Http_Request.poi(Http_Request.java:108)
12-20 00:24:11.622: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7499):     at com.android.upvar.NewPOI.putPOI(NewPOI.java:360)
12-20 00:24:11.622: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7499):     at com.android.upvar.NewPOI.access$6(NewPOI.java:325)
12-20 00:24:11.622: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7499):     at com.android.upvar.NewPOI$5.onClick(NewPOI.java:157)
12-20 00:24:11.622: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7499):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2538)
12-20 00:24:11.622: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7499):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9152)
12-20 00:24:11.622: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7499):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
12-20 00:24:11.622: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7499):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
12-20 00:24:11.622: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7499):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
12-20 00:24:11.622: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7499):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
12-20 00:24:11.622: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7499):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-20 00:24:11.622: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7499):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
12-20 00:24:11.622: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7499):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:842)
12-20 00:24:11.622: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7499):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
12-20 00:24:11.622: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7499):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-20 00:24:11.632: WARN/ActivityManager(3923):   Force finishing activity com.android.upvar/.NewPOI
12-20 00:24:11.636: ERROR/(3923): Dumpstate > /data/log/dumpstate_app_error
```

I don't see why am I getting this exception. I'm just sending a regular image that was taken from a Samsung Galaxay camera (for sure less than 16MB). Any idea?

EDIT: I must add, that the first chunk of code and the second one are on different classes, so the data on the first chunk of code is passed to an object of another class, which passes it to another object of another class, which has the HTTP request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end, te solution was to compress the image to 50% as follows:

```
mBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
```

It reduces the image size and makes it small enough to send it as a String.

Answer (score 1):

Use streaming for your entity so that it consumes only the small buffer size the streams ask for. ByteArrayOutputStream holds all data in memory.

[HTTPClient - Performance Guide](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/performance.html)

Try an implementation like below, which does not create unnecessary in memory objects. Following may not be complete implementation though. Have fun coding!

```
class BitMapRequestEntity extends AbstractHttpEntity {

    private Bitmap bitmap;

    public BitMapRequestEntity(Bitmap mBitmap) {
        super();
        this.bitmap = mBitmap;
    }

    @Override
    public InputStream getContent() throws IOException,
            IllegalStateException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getContentLength() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isRepeatable() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isStreaming() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeTo(OutputStream outstream) throws IOException {
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, outstream);
    }

}
try {
    org.apache.http.client.HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    // PUT
    HttpPut httpput = new HttpPut(KEY_121 + ruta);
    // The exception is thrown when executing next instruction
    httpput.setEntity(new BitMapRequestEntity(mBitmap));
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpput);

    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
    is = entity.getContent();

} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e(TAG, "Error in http connection " + e.toString());
}
```

Comment: Streaming would be good, but where is it in your example? What's the code that does it? I'm kind of confused :S

Comment: The magic happens on the method "writeTo(OutputStream outstream) throws IOException" in "BitMapRequestEntity".

Comment: I like magic :)
So when the PHP server receives it, does it receive it as usual or I have to pull off some other trick to receive it?

Comment: @geeth I cannot get the image in PHP. I have tried $_POST, $_PUT. But I cannot receive any image. Can you please tell me hoe to get the image in backend?

Comment: @Arvind07 Does your android app run without throwing exception? Does your server receive a request? Try changing method of request to POST in both Android client and PHP server.

Answer (score 0):

After you do

```
mBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
```

you have two versions of the image in memory, one as a Bitmap and one in the byte array. Cleaning the former via `Bitmap.recycle()` might help.

Unasked for advice: Does 'multipart form-data' for transmitting images not serve your purpose? This is very memory efficient.

Comment: The recycle method doesn't make a change :S. I never heard about the multipart, but it sounds good. I've looked it up on Google but I'm not sure I understood correctly. So, instead of adding value pairs I would add parts and one of them would be the image? Isn't that the same as before? Or should I chunk the image somehow? Should I add the image as a bitmap, as a file or as a string? Do you know any good tutorial about this?

Comment: Take a look at this: http://paste.pocoo.org/show/GwHe8LrG9DCnq4zuphmK/ (Picked this up from http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/e4230ed22c196772?pli=1)

Comment: Here's one more tutorial: http://blog.tacticalnuclearstrike.com/2010/01/using-multipartentity-in-android-applications/

Multipart mime will chunk the image and send it part by path. And since in this implementation you are using the File body instead of reading the entire image into memory, you'll leave the "when to load the image into memory" part to the system.

Comment: I got that clear now. But what about the server side, do I need to modify my PHP script to handle the request with multi-part? Or does it stay the same?

Comment: I can send the image with multi-part, no error. But now I cannot get the data from $_PUT in PHP as before. How does the data arrive with multi-part?

Comment: I am sorry, I am not a server guy. Though a couple of us successfully put together a system that handles multipart data successfully in the past. It is definitely possible. 

I'd suggest that you google for it, if you didn't already.

Comment: I did, but couldn't find a clear answer. That's why I asked, because I assumed you'd know the whole multi-part solution